# What permissions do I need to give for my server setup?

Tags: permission, apache, php

I am trying to have a server setup for my web app locally on my MacBook Pro. I have installed Apache, PHP successfully and checked out my web app's code to `/var/www` location. Now there's a script in my app that writes a file in `/var/www/someDir`. To do so I am using the following line:

```
$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/abc.ini", "w");
```

And on execution I see the following error in error log.

`PHP Warning:  fopen(/var/www/someDir/abc.ini): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /private/var/www/myscript.php on line 6`

someDir is owned by user `abhilash.goje` (that's me) and group `wheel`. I have tried giving following permissions.

```
$sudo chmod -R 755 www     -> Did not resolve the issue
$sudo chmod -R 775 www     -> Did not resolve the issue
$sudo chmod -R 777 www     -> Resolved the issue, but not safe.
```

permission 777 works but I don't prefer to use this solution as it is not at all safe.
Kindly let me how do I set the correct permissions to this folder.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache is the process that needs to have appropriate permissions to access `/var/www`.  Apache is typically user `_www` of group `_www` on MacOS.  Verify this with:

```
 grep -e '^Group\|^User' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Two lines should be printed.  My output looks like:

```
User _www
Group _www
```

This means that on my system, Apache processes run as user `_www` with group `_www`. If you're using another configuration, check the appropriate config file for the same parameters and replace `_www` in the following solution if yours differs.

1. Change the group of `/var/www` with: `chgrp -R _www /var/www`
2. Change the permissions to add group write with: `chmod -R 775 /var/www`

That should fix the error.

As an extra step, you can change the ownership of `/var/www` to `_www` and then add yourself to that group to maintain your read and write privileges.